# generate custom key with $add angularfire

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

How can I generate a custom key in array inside angularfire when I add a new record with the `$add` function. Just look at when the is the comment below in the source code. This is my code below but still get the random key generated by firebase.

```js
register : function(user){
  return simpleLogin.$createUser({
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password
  }).then(function(regUser){
    //console.dir(regUser);
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users');
    var firebaseUsers = $firebaseArray(ref);
    var userInfo = {
      date: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
      regUser: regUser.uid,
      firstname: user.firstname,
      lastname: user.lastname,
      email: user.email
    }

    //this is when i want to generate the key
    firebaseUsers.$add(userInfo).then(function(ref) {

    });
  });
},//register
```

[image: still got the random key with the $add function]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `$add` will simply always result in a so-called *push id*. If you don't want to use those push ids to identify the objects, the solution is to not call `$add`/`push`.

Instead you can just access the child that you want to create directly:

```
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users');
    var userInfo = {
      date: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
      regUser: regUser.uid,
      firstname: user.firstname,
      lastname: user.lastname,
      email: user.email
    }

    ref.child(regUser.uid).set(userInfo);
```

Two things to note here:

1. the snippet creates the child node under `regUser.uid`. If you need another key, you can substitute that.
2. this snippet doesn't use AngularFire, but instead uses the Firebase JavaScript SDK directly. Since AngularFire is built on the JavaScript SDK, they interoperate perfectly. So if you need an operation that isn't immediately obvious in AngularFire, it might be worth it to check whether you can accomplish it (more easily) with the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK.

Comment: i dont found a way to create a custom key by only using the API of angularfire

Comment: Makes sense. AngularFire simplifies the interaction between Firebase and the Angular views. You're not displaying anything in this snippet, so it doesn't need to be written in AngularFire.

Answer (score 0):

with the help of mester Frank van Puffelen above I modify the code :

```js
register : function(user){
  return simpleLogin.$createUser({
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password
  }).then(function(regUser){
    //console.dir(regUser);
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users');
    var firebaseUsers = $firebaseArray(ref);
    var userInfo = {
      date: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
      regUser: regUser.uid,
      firstname: user.firstname,
      lastname: user.lastname,
      email: user.email
    }

    //the added portion of code
    ref.child(regUser.uid).set(userInfo);

    firebaseUsers.$add(userInfo).then(function(ref) {

    });





  });
},//register
```

and i got the result i want , in angularfire API there is no functions ( 'child()' and set() )  but as mentionned in the post of mester **Frank van Puffelen**  angularfire API is built up on firebase API .

and this is my capture image from my database firebase.

[image: capture from my firebase database]